# Proving that rotation is an isometry in the complex plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Consider the rotation $ρ_θ : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ about the origin with angle $θ$ in counterclockwise direction; this can be described by the map $ρ_θ(z) = e
^{iθ} z$. Prove that $ρ_θ$ is an isometry of $\Bbb C$.

I know that rotation in general is an isometry. Even taking $d(ρ_θ(z), ρ_θ(u)) = e
^{iθ} z - e^{iθ} u = e^{iθ}( z - u)$, I don't see how $e^{iθ}( z - u) = (z-u)$, which would make this true. But what allows $e^{iθ}$ to not affect the distance?

Any help completing this proof is appreciated.

Comment: What you really need to prove is not that $ e^{i\theta} (z-u) = (z-u) $ but that $|e^{i\theta}(z-u)| = |(z-u)|$

Comment: You need to use $|u-v|$ instead of $u-v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$ then $|u-v|=|e^{i\theta}u-e^{i\theta}v|=|e^{i\theta}||u-v|$ since  $|e^{i\theta}|=1$

Answer (score 1):

$e^{i\theta}(z-u)$ is not the Distance. The distance is $\vert e^{i\theta}(z-u) \vert$. Now it should be quite simple to continue.